# How can I use nmap to list whether or not the addresses in a subnet are active or not using Python

Tags: python, nmap, cidr

I know that nmap has the ability to ping sweep and output a list of only active IPs, but I am scouring the net to figure how to list whether or not an IP is active using CIDR notation. (ie for 1.1.1.1/32 list if the addresses are active or inactive). I have also been looking into netaddr and scapy but I can't see how I would make that work. I am attempting to do this using a python script.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this under python?

Comment: I am trying to script this using python.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a host is alive, or if it is listening on certain ports? Are you trying to be stealthy? Is this just an exploratory exercise? There are too many variables for me to give a concise answer.

Comment: I apologize about the vagueness. I am attempting to determine if the host is alive as an audit exercise (so I am not worried about stealth). I will be given a subnet and need to write a script that will ping each individual address in the subnet and report back as to whether or not the IP is alive, I will then have it export the results to a csv.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an opensource library called [python-iptools](https://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/) which has the ability to convert from CIDR notation to an IP range.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for doing this in Python would be to use Scapy. You can easily create a ping (ICMP Echo Request) packet, set its destination to a CIDR range, and then "send" it, which will sequentially send to every address in the range:

```
>>> p = IP(dst="10.0.0.0/30") / ICMP()
>>> sr(p,timeout=5)
Begin emission:
Finished to send 4 packets.
**..................
Received 20 packets, got 2 answers, remaining 2 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:2 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:2 Other:0>)
```

Getting the output of the `sr` function (or whatever method you choose to use to send the packets) is left to you. An alternative to get the addresses (leaving the packet generation up to you) would be to use the [`ipaddr`](https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) library, which has an `IPv4Network` object that can iterate over a CIDR network.

Lastly, I am obliged to point out that Nmap can accept target specifications in CIDR format (e.g. `192.168.1.0/24`, `example.com/26`, `10.0.0.0/8`, etc.)